# Py.test cannot find csv file

Tags: python, pytest

I have a folder structure like this

```
App
--App
  --app.py       
--Docs
--Tests
  --test_app.py
  --sample.csv
```

In my test_app.py, I have a line to open the sample.csv file. When I run py.test command on the root `App` level. It throws errors saying that sample.csv does not exist. How should I configure py.test so that it can find my sample.csv file?

**Edit:**

```
import pandas as pd

class TestReturns:
    def test_annualized(self):
        pd.read_csv("sample.csv")
    def test_rebalancing(self):
        assert 1 == 1
```

Nothing fancy about the test. I am just trying out how to configure paths.

Comment: Can you post your code?

Comment: @AnkitJaiswal Just updated to include my code

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If the csv file is always in the same directory as the test file you should use `__file__`, something like:

```
def test_annualized():
    fname = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'sample.csv')
    pd.read_csv(fname)
```

See the python [datamodel docs](http://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html?highlight=__file__) for some scant notes on `__file__`.

Comment: But with this setup, where is py.test looking for the file?

Comment: This exact code looks in the same directory as the test file lives.  `__file__` is the path of the test module so calling `dirname()` on it returns the directory of the test module.